# How to plot latitude and longitude using Google Geocoder webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, google-geocoder

How do I plot latitude and logitude using Google Geocoder webservice in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

There is a full tutorial on how to use Google maps in java script, so if you are using asp.net to display a web page, it isn't too hard:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

If you are trying to plot lat and long on to a custom made maps, you would have to deal with the fact that the earth is basically a sphere, and do 3D modeling.  Its quite math intensive, and this probably isn't the correct place for this question.